# Is it possible to share an enum declaration between C# and unmanaged C++?

Tags: c#, c++, enums, native, managed

Is there a way to share an enum definition between native (unmanaged) C++ and (managed) C#?

I have the following enum used in completely unmanaged code:

```
enum MyEnum { myVal1, myVal2 };
```

Our application sometimes uses a managed component.  That C# component gets the enum item values as ints via a managed C++ interop dll (from the native dll). (The interop dll only loads if the C# component is needed.)  The C# component has duplicated the enum definition:

```
public enum MyEnum { myVal1, myVal2 };
```

Is there a way to eliminate the duplication without turning the native C++ dll into a managed dll?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a single .cs file and share it between both projects. `#include` in C++ on a .cs file should be no problem.

This would be an example .cs file:

```
#if !__LINE__    
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public 
#endif

// shared enum for both C, C++ and C#
enum MyEnum { myVal1, myVal2 };

#if !__LINE__
}
#endif
```

If you want multiple enums in one file, you can do this (although you have to temporarily define public to be nothing for C / C++):

```
#if __LINE__
#define public
#else
namespace MyNamespace
{
#endif

    public enum MyEnum { MyEnumValue1, MyEnumValue2 };
    public enum MyEnum2 { MyEnum2Value1, MyEnum2Value2 };
    public enum MyEnum3 { MyEnum3Value1, MyEnum3Value2 };

#if __LINE__
#undef public
#else
}
#endif
```

Comment: I just tested something similar - but the file is named MyEnum.cs. So that it compiles is C# without any special rules. In my C++ file this works:       #include "MyEnum.cs"

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Confirmed it works as expected - no change to C# project settings (other than adding link to the new cs file).  Funny to see a #include of a .cs file in a C++.

Comment: Just use: #if __cpulsplus_cli

Comment: @YochaiTimmer 1. there's a typo, should be: `__cplusplus_cli`; 2. in my opinion, `__cpulsplus_cli` cannot help distinguish unmanaged C++ (pure c++ without /clr) and C#, so it is not suitable for this question.

Comment: Look at the edit history. It seems this answer has been edited quite a few times by random people. The original check i used, was #if WIN32 ... that is used in cli compiler and not c#

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for sharing!

I played around a bit and found a way to have multiple enum and constant declarations without having tons of extra lines :)

```
// This is a valid C, C++ and C# file :)
#if __LINE__
#define public
#else
namespace MyCSharpNamespace{
#endif

    public enum MyConstant { MaxStr = 256 };
    public enum MyEnum1{ MyEnum1_A, MyEnum1_B };
    public enum MyEnum2{ MyEnum2_A, MyEnum2_B };

#if __LINE__
#undef public
#else
}
#endif
```

Remember to name your file *.cs

Answer (score 3):

You can expose the C# library to COM and then import the type library into the unmanaged code - this way you will be able to use the enum defined in C# library in the unmanaged library.

Comment: That's an interesting approach.  It has the side-effect that an otherwise unexposed enum becomes COM public.  Unfortunately, the C# library may not run ever run/load due to framework incompatibility on target OSs.

Comment: @sean, you can selectively make specific enums public and others not using the ComVisibleAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

Unmanaged C++ and C# live in two different worlds, so no there is no way to use the same enum, without changing the c++ DLL into a managed one.

And even then, you'd probably need the duplication in the managed C++ DLL.

A C++ enum is much like a list of constants, whereas a C# enum inherits the Enum class, and thus provides quite a few "tricks". So as you can see, they're *very* different.

If it doesn't matter whether the native C++ DLL is native or managed, I'd turn it into a managed one and wrap the native calls inside a managed C++ Layer.

That way you can have the enum duplication inside the C++ DLL, and also you can get rid of all the interop at the same time :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem in the past and solved it using preprocessor definitions.

In your unmanaged code, inside a header that can also be included by your managed wrapper, place your enumeration items into a #define.

Then, in your managed and unmanaged enumeration definitions, use the same #define for both usages.

The movement of the enumerations between the managed and unmanaged world looks slightly nasty (basically a cast is needed), but to your caller in the unmanaged world, it'll look and feel fine.

Good luck,

Comment: I'm missing something... use a header in C#?