# Seeming evaluation of preprocessor code inside a #if false block

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, undef

I'm working in C# via MonoDevelop 4.0.1 (Current version for Unity),
and have hit a seeming language weirdness.

Here's my entire .cs file:

```
#if false

#define foo

#endif

class myClass {
  int member;
}

#if false

#error this error does not trigger

#undef foo
// "cannot define or undefine preprocessor symbols after first token in file

#endif
```

I understand the rule about not `#undef`ing a preprocessor symbol after a token has been declared, but in this case i'm *not* `#undef`ing because the `#undef` is inside a `#if false`.

This example is not entirely contrived, it's an attempt to get a single source file to compile in both C# and C++ via the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954321/is-it-possible-to-share-an-enum-declaration-between-c-sharp-and-unmanaged-c).

Comment: I find even more weird try to compile same C# and C++ code without coding for the proper language!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't complain about the same code. I think you have discovered a bug in Mono.