# How to skip a C++ preprocessor directive in C#

Tags: c#, c++, directive, preprocessor

I am trying to use the same class in C++ and C#. I am using preprocessor directives to scape code differences. However, I cannot skip C++ directives (as `#include` or `#define`) even when they are inside an `#if` `#endif` section.

The following code compiles in C++, but not in C#:

```
#if !NET
#pragma once
#include <string>      //<-- C# error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected
#define public public: //<-- C# error CS1025: Single-line comment or end-of-line expected
#endif

#if NET
namespace A.B {
#else
namespace A::B {
   using namespace std;
#endif
   class C {
      string str;
      public C() {str = "test";}
   };
}

#if !NET
#undef public
#endif
```

**Questions:**

- Why can I not do this?
- Why C# preprocessor tries to understand `#include` or `#define` directives if they are inside an `#if !NET` section?
- Is there anyway to do it?

##### EDIT:

Ouch! Rereading [chapter 6.5.5 of the C# standard specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/standard-v6/standard/lexical-structure.md#655-conditional-compilation-directives), I notice the following paragraph:

> Any remaining conditional sections are skipped and no tokens, except those for pre-processing directives, are generated from the source code. Therefore skipped source code, except pre-processing directives, may be lexically incorrect. **Skipped pre-processing directives shall be lexically correct** but are not otherwise processed. Within a conditional section that is being skipped any nested conditional sections (contained in nested `#if...#endif` constructs) are also skipped.

- So, ok, my first question is answered.
- What about the second one: Why pre-processing directives shall be lexical correct?
- However, does anybody know how to avoid this limitation? How to make the above code work?

Comment: OT: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) Doing it in a header file is plain wrong (IMO)

Comment: I know. This is an example code. The goal is to ask about skipping C++ directives in C# writing a code as easy as possible.

Comment: PErhaps the C# "preprocessor" just doesn't work as the C++ preprocessor? What does its documentation say?

Comment: Also, when you get this to work, please never do that again! It's just bad, and no one sane would want to ever even look at code like that.

Comment: How do you define the macro? `#if !NET` is true if `NET` is defined like `#define NET` or `-D NET`. Assign some non zero value to it or use `#ifndef NET`

Comment: Given the massively different syntax it's almost universally a bad idea to even attempt this.

Comment: @273K `-D` defines the macro to `1` by default, I believe.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good to know it, my command line arguments can be reduced.

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid, but I don't see why you would want to compile the same file as both C++ and C# - Why don't you just create two different files and compile each as their own language?

Comment: I can see that a typo in one `#endif` could really mess things up, so requiring only valid directives seems reasonable. Also, in C++ it is specifically forbidden the use `#define` to modify keywords, like `private`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am developing a tool where frontend is C# and backend is C++ and both need some common classes. Nowadays I have two files for each common class, one for C++, other for C# and when I change something in one file, I need to remember to change in the other side. I am trying to mix both files in one to improve maintainability and traceability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found a method to solve this issue using two files:

**Note:** It may not be the best idea, but I can't find a better one than this.

```
/*** myfile.hpp ***/
#pragma once

#include <string>

#define public public:
#include "myfile.cs"
#undef public

/*** myfile.cs ***/
#if NET
namespace A.B {
#else
namespace A::B {
   using string = std::string;
#endif
   class C {
      string str;
      public C() {str = "test";}
   };
}
```

With these two files, on C++ `myfile.hpp` should be included, and on C# only `myfile.cs` is needed.

The idea is taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56839291/13087883